# Novel with stellar sailing ship controlled with 'freely-given' stone

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel I read years ago (likely late 80s or 90s) about stellar sailing ships that used sails to travel the stellar winds.

The ship's captain used a stone to control the ships and it had to be given free to another to be active.